# Transfer rows from one database to another

Tags: sql, vistadb

This may be answered already somewhere in this forum, but I can't seem to find a good example since I'm using Vistadb 6.

I have to 2 databases; one is the main database, and the other is the backup copy of the main database (with the same structure). I can transfer rows from the customers, inventory tables etc. But when I try to transfer the orders table, only the main (`Order`) table rows are transferred, but not the Order Details rows.

The child table rows like Details, Payments are not transferred. I'm using a List box to store the OrderId number. There may be more than 1 order number in the list to transfer rows, this depends on if the user selects more than 1 row to transfer.

How it is supposed to work:

1. User selects the backup database copy. (ie. Backup1.vdb6, or Backup2.vdb6, etc.)
2. User selects what to transfer (ie...Orders records for example)
3. User selects more than 1 order # to transfer (ie.100, 305, 422, etc.)
4. The Order numbers are in a list box control

   ```
   -100
   -305
   -422
   ```
5. Need to transfer the records: start with the first record to transfer, ie..100 copy the Orders Table, then the details table, followed by the payments table.
6. Move to the next Order # (ie..305, 422, etc.) and repeat the same for all the Order numbers that need to be transferred to the main database.

This works it transfers all the rows from `MyFile` database to the main database `Orders` table. But it does not transfer the `OrderDetails` rows or the `OrderPayment` rows.

```
private void TransferOrders()
{
    // Backup Database
    MyFile = (string) TreeListTransfer.FocusedNode[0];
    string VdbConn1 = $"Data Source={bPath}{MyFile}.vdb6";

    try
    {
        // I suspect the problem may be in this, not sure.
        for (int i = 0; i < LstFiles.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            LstFiles.SelectedIndex = i;

            // Get the Order number from the list, call it FileId
            FileId = Convert.ToInt32(LstFiles.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            Standard.StrSql = @"SELECT OrderId, OrderType, ClientId, OrderDate, DueDate, SubTotal, SalesTax, CityTax, LaborTax, Delivery, Discount, OrderTotal
                                FROM Orders
                                WHERE (OrderId = @OrderId)";

            using (VistaDBConnection conn1 = new(VdbConn1))
            {
                // Open the connection
                conn1.Open();

                using VistaDBCommand cmd1 = new(Standard.StrSql, conn1);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", FileId);

                using VistaDBDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr["OrderId"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        Orders.OrderId = (int) dr["OrderId"];
                    }

                    if (dr["OrderType"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        Orders.OrderType = (string) dr["OrderType"];
                    }

                    if (dr["ClientId"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        Clients.ClientId = (int) dr["ClientId"];
                    }

                    if (dr["OrderDate"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        Orders.OrderDate = (DateTime) dr["OrderDate"];
                    }

                     if (dr["DueDate"] != DBNull.Value)
                         {
                         Orders.DueDate = (DateTime) dr["DueDate"];
                         }

                     if (dr["SubTotal"] != DBNull.Value)
                         {
                         Orders.SubTotal = (decimal) dr["SubTotal"];
                         }

                     if (dr["SalesTax"] != DBNull.Value)
                         {
                         Orders.SalesTax = (decimal) dr["SalesTax"];
                         }

                     if (dr["CityTax"] != DBNull.Value)
                         {
                         Orders.CityTax = (decimal) dr["CityTax"];
                         }

                     if (dr["LaborTax"] != DBNull.Value)
                         {
                         Orders.LaborTax = (decimal) dr["LaborTax"];
                         }

                     if (dr["Delivery"] != DBNull.Value)
                         {
                         Orders.Delivery = (decimal) dr["Delivery"];
                         }

                     if (dr["Discount"] != DBNull.Value)
                         {
                         Orders.Discount = (decimal) dr["Discount"];
                         }

                     if (dr["OrderTotal"] != DBNull.Value)
                         {
                         Orders.OrderTotal = (decimal) dr["OrderTotal"];
                         }

                     }

                 }

//Open the main database using a new conncection.
             //Add the Contents to the main Database
             using (VistaDBConnection conn2 = new(Settings.Default.someSetting))
                 {
                 conn2.Open();

                     Standard.StrSql = @"INSERT INTO Orders(OrderType, ClientId, OrderDate, DueDate, SubTotal, SalesTax, CityTax, LaborTax, Delivery, Discount, OrderTotal)
                   VALUES (@OrderType, @ClientId, @OrderDate, @DueDate, @SubTotal, @SalesTax, @CityTax, @LaborTax, @Delivery, @Discount, @OrderTotal)";
                     

                 using VistaDBCommand cmd2 = new(Standard.StrSql, conn2);

                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderType", Orders.OrderType);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientId", Clients.ClientId);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", Orders.OrderDate);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", Orders.DueDate);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTotal", Orders.SubTotal);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesTax", Orders.SalesTax);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityTax", Orders.CityTax);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LaborTax", Orders.LaborTax);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Delivery", Orders.Delivery);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", Orders.Discount);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderTotal", Orders.OrderTotal);


                 cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
             //Transfer the Order Details
             TransferOrderDetails();
//End of the i
             }


         }
     catch (Exception ex)
         {
         XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Transfer Order Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         }

     }

//This is the method to get the order details 

        private void TransferOrderDetails()
            {
            MyFile = (string) TreeListTransfer.FocusedNode[0];
            string VdbConn1 = $"Data Source={bPath}{MyFile}.vdb6";
            //Go get the last OrderId number so we can focus on it
//This gets the Last OrderId number from the main database
            int MyOrderId = Orders.GetMaxOrderId(OrderId: 0);

            try
                {
                Standard.StrSql = @"SELECT ItemId, OrderId, InventoryId, Category, Description, Qnty, Unit, RetailPrice, Total
                                  FROM OrderDetails
                                  WHERE (OrderId = @OrderId)
                                  ORDER BY ItemId";

                using (VistaDBConnection conn1 = new(VdbConn1))
                    {
                    //Open the connection
                    conn1.Open();

                    using VistaDBCommand cmd1 = new(Standard.StrSql, conn1);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", MyOrderId);

                    using VistaDBDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                        {
                        while (dr.Read())
                            {
                            if (dr["OrderId"] != DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                Orders.OrderId = (int) dr["OrderId"];
                                }

                            if (dr["InventoryId"] != DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                Inventory.InventoryId = (int) dr["InventoryId"];
                                }

                            if (dr["Category"] != DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                OrderDetails.ItemCat = (string) dr["Category"];
                                }

                            if (dr["Description"] != DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                OrderDetails.ItemDesc = (string) dr["Description"];
                                }

                            if (dr["Qnty"] != DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                OrderDetails.qnty = (decimal) dr["Qnty"];
                                }

                            if (dr["Unit"] != DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                OrderDetails.ItemUnit = (string) dr["Unit"];
                                }

                            if (dr["RetailPrice"] != DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                OrderDetails.ItemRetail = (decimal) dr["RetailPrice"];
                                }

                            if (dr["Total"] != DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                OrderDetails.ItemTotal = (decimal) dr["Total"];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                //Save Everything to the Database
                using (VistaDBConnection conn = new(Settings.Default.someSetting))
                    {
                    //Open the Connection
                    conn.Open();

                    Standard.StrSql = @"INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderId, InventoryId, Category, Description, Qnty, Unit, RetailPrice, Total)
                             VALUES (@OrderId, @InventoryId, @Category, @Details, @Qnty, @Unit, @Retail, @Total)";

                    using VistaDBCommand cmd = new(Standard.StrSql, conn);
                        {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", MyOrderId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InventoryId", Inventory.InventoryId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", OrderDetails.ItemCat);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", OrderDetails.ItemDesc);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qnty", OrderDetails.qnty);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", OrderDetails.ItemUnit);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Retail", OrderDetails.ItemRetail);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", OrderDetails.ItemTotal);

                        //Execute the Query
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                    //Transfer the payments related to the order
                    TransferOrderPayments();

                    }

                }
            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Transfer Order Items Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

            }
```

For the sake of brevity, I left out the payments table records, but it is the same procedure as the Order details.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to keep the first database connection open and data reader in order to transfer the records to the table. Once I did that, the records display in the main database, Order Details, and Order Payments tables.
Thank You to anyone who was working on this.